# Having issues with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel that makes me run the script twice to get desired file

Tags: perl

I have a tab-delimited file that I want to write into Excel. I've used Spreadsheet::WriteExcel, but the first run will only write 99 rows in Excel, and then stop halfway through the 100th row. I've checked my tab-del .txt and there are no extra whitespaces or new lines. All lines within the .txt file has 14 or 15 values, and the print out `print $row size` shows 14/15 except for the last row, which shows `6`. When I run it again, it shows the remaining rows but also additional rows from the second run. Can someone help review my code to see where the problem may be?

```
        open(FIRST, '>>', $first_file) || die "";
        #create tab delimted file
        close(FIRST);
        open(SECOND, $first_file) || die "cannot open $ind_output to write to excel";
        my $xl_row_num = 0;
        my $xl_file = "tab_ann.xls";
        my $xl = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($xl_file);
        my $txt_xl = $xl -> add_worksheet();
        my $format = $xl -> add_format();
        $format->set_color('red');
        while(my $line = <SECOND>){
            #create an array containing each value the current line
            my @data = split("\t", $line); 
            #my $size = scalar(@data);
            #print "row size:\t".$size."\n";
            print "row rum:\t".$xl_row_num."\n";
            #Write each value in array in separate cell in a single row.
            for(my $col=0; $col < $size+1; $col++){
                   $txt_xl->write($xl_row_num, $col, $data[$col], $format);
            }
        @data=();
        $xl_row_num++;
        }
        close SECOND;
```

Comment: I would, at least, chomp($line) in the loop while you read from SECOND. I don't think that will fix your problem, but those line feeds don't belong into the excel sheet.
The fact that, when you run it again, you duplicate your output, is because you're using ">>" when creating the file, so you actually append instead of overwriting.
If, after the first run, your $first_file contains everything it should, but the excel doesn't, the only thing i can think of is some bizarre misconfiguration of a network file system, with data not being flushed correctly.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm, I originally had the `>` write option and discovered that the $first_file wasn't the problem through `>>`. Forgot about `chomp()`, but no luck there but I appreciate the input.

Comment: So let me get this straight:  You write the tab-delimited file, and then read it back in within the same script, in order to generate your Excel file.  The Excel generating code looks fine.  (I might add a `$xl->close()` to be safe, but it isn't strictly needed in this case.)  The issue seems to be betweel `close FIRST` and `open SECOND`.  Are you sure the code between `open FIRST` and `close FIRST` fully wrote the file you're re-reading?  Does `close FIRST` return an error?

Comment: Yea, I have `xl_file1` that serves as a master list of records that I need to break up into smaller excel files by person's name. The tab-delimited file is an annotation/subset of `xl_file1`. I've made sure the txt file is closed before opening it for WriteExcel, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Are you certain at the point you `close FIRST` that the file contains everything you expect?

Comment: Yep. I made a test file using sequential numbers and it extracts everything that I want.